# declaring propsType in App component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to declare props type for my app component

```
App.propTypes = {
    propNumber: React.PropTypes.number,
    propOject: React.PropTypes.object,
    propString: React.PropTypes.string
}
```

It's giving me

> cannot read property 'number' of undefined error

Comment: Did you import proptypes? Also, in [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) example, there is no `React` preceding `PropTypes.Number`, so that may be your problem

Comment: thank you now its working i didn't know that now we have to import PropTypes